# Select what methods from super class to Implement/Override in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Is there a way to select/see what methods you can override/implement from the super class in xcode and have them created?

An example of what I mean is in Visual Studio you can select from a drop down at the top of the class file and if that method is not in your class it will get created.

In Android Studio you can right click on the class name/Generate/Override Methods and it brings up a list of the class methods that you can override.

Does such a thing exist in xcode so that I dont have to keep looking at the online documentation when I need to find something?

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you're asking for well enough to know that this isn't exactly it however I couldn't pass up an opportunity get this very useful technique on "the stack(overflow)"! ;-) Add this method to any (NSObject sub-)class and it will log all unimplemented methods that the runtime is attempting to resolve against your class.

```
/*******************************************************************************
 ** Function - resolveInstanceMethod
 **
 ** This is an AWESOME debugging method that allows you to see what methods
 ** the runtime is attempting to resolve against your class
 ********************************************************************************/
#ifdef DEBUG
+ (BOOL) resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)sel {
    BOOL result = [super resolveInstanceMethod:sel];
    // comment out this next line if you want to 
    // log methods implemented by the super class
    if (!result)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unimplemented Instance method: \'%s\'", sel_getName(sel));
    }
    return (result);
}   /* resolveInstanceMethod: */
#endif  // def DEBUG
```